# Trying to separate polygon data into x and y coordinates but get error " 'MultiPolygon' object has no attribute 'exterior'"

Tags: python, geospatial, polygon, bokeh, geopandas

I am new to Python and I am trying to separate polygon data into x and y coordinates. I keep getting error: "AttributeError: ("'MultiPolygon' object has no attribute 'exterior'", 'occurred at index 1')"

From what I understand Python object MultiPolygon does not contain data exterior. But how do I remedy this to make the function work?

```
def getPolyCoords(row, geom, coord_type):
    """Returns the coordinates ('x' or 'y') of edges of a Polygon exterior"""

    # Parse the exterior of the coordinate
    geometry = row[geom]

    if coord_type == 'x':
        # Get the x coordinates of the exterior
        return list( geometry.exterior.coords.xy[0] )
    elif coord_type == 'y':
        # Get the y coordinates of the exterior
        return list( geometry.exterior.coords.xy[1] )


# Get the Polygon x and y coordinates
grid['x'] = grid.apply(getPolyCoords, geom='geometry', coord_type='x', axis=1)
grid['y'] = grid.apply(getPolyCoords, geom='geometry', coord_type='y', axis=1)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-73511dbae283> in <module>
      1 # Get the Polygon x and y coordinates
----> 2 grid['x'] = grid.apply(getPolyCoords, geom='geometry', coord_type='x', axis=1)
      3 grid['y'] = grid.apply(getPolyCoords, geom='geometry', coord_type='y', axis=1)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in apply(self, func, axis, broadcast, raw, reduce, result_type, args, **kwds)
   6012                          args=args,
   6013                          kwds=kwds)
-> 6014         return op.get_result()
   6015 
   6016     def applymap(self, func):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in get_result(self)
    140             return self.apply_raw()
    141 
--> 142         return self.apply_standard()
    143 
    144     def apply_empty_result(self):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in apply_standard(self)
    246 
    247         # compute the result using the series generator
--> 248         self.apply_series_generator()
    249 
    250         # wrap results

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in apply_series_generator(self)
    275             try:
    276                 for i, v in enumerate(series_gen):
--> 277                     results[i] = self.f(v)
    278                     keys.append(v.name)
    279             except Exception as e:

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py in f(x)
     72         if kwds or args and not isinstance(func, np.ufunc):
     73             def f(x):
---> 74                 return func(x, *args, **kwds)
     75         else:
     76             f = func

<ipython-input-4-8c3864d38986> in getPolyCoords(row, geom, coord_type)
      7     if coord_type == 'x':
      8         # Get the x coordinates of the exterior
----> 9         return list( geometry.exterior.coords.xy[0] )
     10     elif coord_type == 'y':
     11         # Get the y coordinates of the exterior

AttributeError: ("'MultiPolygon' object has no attribute 'exterior'", 'occurred at index 1')
```

Answer (score 5):

I have updated your function `getPolyCoords()` to enable the handling of other geometry types, namely, `MultiPolygon`, `Point`, and `LineString`. Hope it works for your project.

```
def getPolyCoords(row, geom, coord_type):
    """
    Returns the coordinates ('x|y') of edges/vertices of a Polygon/others
    Args:
    - row: the row object from a geodataframe; i.e.   df.loc[1]
    - geom: the name of "geometry" column, usually "geometry"
    - coord_type: 'x', or 'y'
    ...
    Valid geometrie types 'Polygon', 'Point', 'LineString', 'MultiLineString', 'MultiPolygon'
    """

    # Parse the geometries and grab the coordinate
    geometry = row[geom]
    #print(geometry.type)

    if geometry.type=='Polygon':
        if coord_type == 'x':
            # Get the x coordinates of the exterior
            # Interior is more complex: xxx.interiors[0].coords.xy[0]
            return list( geometry.exterior.coords.xy[0] )
        elif coord_type == 'y':
            # Get the y coordinates of the exterior
            return list( geometry.exterior.coords.xy[1] )

    if geometry.type in ['Point', 'LineString']:
        if coord_type == 'x':
            return list( geometry.xy[0] )
        elif coord_type == 'y':
            return list( geometry.xy[1] )

    if geometry.type=='MultiLineString':
        all_xy = []
        # updated code, using .geoms
        for ea in geometry.geoms:
            if coord_type == 'x':
                all_xy.append(list( ea.xy[0] ))
            elif coord_type == 'y':
                all_xy.append(list( ea.xy[1] ))
        return all_xy

    if geometry.type=='MultiPolygon':
        all_xy = []
        for ea in geometry.geoms:
            if coord_type == 'x':
                all_xy.append(list( ea.exterior.coords.xy[0] ))
            elif coord_type == 'y':
                all_xy.append(list( ea.exterior.coords.xy[1] ))
        return all_xy

    else:
        # Finally, return empty list for unknown geometries
        return []
```

The portion of the code that handles `MultiPolygon` geometries has a loop that iterates for all the member `Polygon`s, and processes each of them. The code for `Polygon` handling is reused there.

**Sample code to use the function**

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, LineString, MultiLineString

# Create a sample geodataframe

a = LineString([(0, 0), (0, 0.4), (1, 0.4), (1, 0)])
b = MultiLineString([[(0, 1.6), (0.5, 2.4), (1.2, 2.6), (1.3, 1.7)], [(0, 1.5), (1, 1.3), (1.5, 1.6)]])
c = Polygon([(1.4, 0), (1.5, .75), (2, 1), (2.1, 0)])
df = gpd.GeoDataFrame({"ID": ["a", "b", "c"], "geometry": [a, b, c]})
```

[image: sample1]

Sample code that makes use of the function:-

```
r0 = df.loc[0]  # lower-left LineString
r1 = df.loc[1]  # upper-left MultiLineString
r2 = df.loc[2]  # lower-right Polygon
print( getPolyCoords(r0, "geometry", "x"))  #[0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0]
print( getPolyCoords(r1, "geometry", "y"))  #[[1.6, 2.4, 2.6, 1.7], [1.5, 1.3, 1.6]]
print( getPolyCoords(r2, "geometry", "x"))  #[1.4, 1.5, 2.0, 2.1, 1.4]
```

Answer (score 1):

See the shapely docs about [multipolygons](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#MultiPolygons)

A multipolygon is a sequence of polygons, and it is the polygon object that has the exterior attribute. You need to iterate through the polygons of the multipolygon, and get `exterior.coords` of each polygon.

In practice, you probably want your geometries in the GeoDataFrame to be polygons, rather than multipolygons, but they aren't. You may want to split the rows in which have multipolygons into multiple rows each with one polygon (or not, depending on your use case)